# .htaccess changes show folder name after redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a shared server with GoDaddy in which I host different web sites with different domain names. My folder structure is like this:

```
-- root (/)
     |-- web1
     |    |-- index.php
     |    |-- ...
     |
     |-- web2
     |    |-- index.php
     |    |-- ...
     |
     |-- web3
     |    |-- index.php
     |    |-- ...
     |
     |-- .htaccess
```

For each site, I have a domain (let's call it web1.com, web2.com, and web3.com respectively) that I redirect using the .htaccess in the root folder like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  web1.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web1/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /web1/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  web2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web2/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /web2/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  web3.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web3/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /web3/$1 [L,NC]
```

This has been working fine for me so far, but now I have a problem: I got an SSL certificate that I want to use with web1, web2 and web3 and it works fine, but due to some restrictions on the names I can include in the certificate (5 only), I want to redirect all the traffic from www.web1.com to web1.com (**remove the www.**) and also I want to redirect all the traffic **from http to https**.

**Inside the folder web1**, I created a new .htaccess with these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# redirect from http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

And it does what it is supposed to do, but here's the problem: the URL is not `https://web1.com/` as I'd expect but `https://web1.com/web1/index.php`. If I remove the `/web1/` folder from the URL, then I get a 404 error.

Now my questions (thanks for reading until here):

- Why is the folder included in the URL after I do the redirections? (and how could I fix it?)
- Is it possible to achieve this the way I'm doing it (with .htaccess inside the web1 folder), or should I simplify and move those rules to the .htaccess in the root folder?

  - Probably moving the rules to the parent's .htaccess would fix the issue, is it OK to have "site specific" rules in the root .htaccess?
- Is there a better way of doing it? I'm feel like I'm trying to re-invent the wheel (because probably I am :S).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing `/web1/index.php` instead of `/` because of that rule in root .htaccess that is making `REQUEST_URI` to `/web1/index.php`. You need to capture URI value from `THE_REQUEST` variable which doesn't change with application of prior rules.

Have this rule in `/web1/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web1/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+web1/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://web1.com/%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Also you can see how 2 rules could be combined into one here.